# Differenciation problem of a linear transformation, does somebody has an idea?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation and suppose that T verifies

$$\lim_{v\rightarrow \overrightarrow{0}} \frac{\| Tv \|}{\| v \|} = 0,$$

show that T is the zero linear transformation, meaning that for each $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $T(w) = \overrightarrow 0$.

I have been struggling with this problem for some hours and cant arrive to the desired conclusion. Does somebody has an idea to help me solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Every linear transformation defined on a finite dimensional vector space is bounded. So $\|Tv\| \le M\|v\|$ for some $M\in \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: You are right! thank you.